# How can make a matrix row type

Tags: r, matrix, subset

`x_[1:2,i+1] = A %*% xp[1:2,i] + U * C[i]`

when I made this cord, R was displayed below error.

`"incorrect number of subscripts on matrix"`

so, I tried to debug it, and I found that the output is returning col type.

For example, if a matrix has consisted of 1 to 12, nrow =3

```
a = matrix(1:12, 3)
a
#1 4 7 10
#2 5 8 11
#3 6 9 12
```

when I call `a[1:2, 2]`, the result is 4, 5.

That's why the error is showed in my cord.

How can I make it save row type?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and give a [mcve] in your question!

Comment: Hi, can you clarify what outcome you expect from `a[1:2, 2]` please (do you want `a[1:2, 2, drop=FALSE]` ?)